# Как в поток передать параметр?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Появилась необходимость передать в поток параметр. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Вы не должны думать в терминах потоков, они слишком низкоуровневые. Используйте `Task`, и всё будет легко и очевидно.

Comment: я хочу получить на выходе не удобный для меня код, а "быстрый"

Comment: Тогда не используйте потоки. Task.Run выполняется на пуле потоков, для него не нужно создавать новый поток. Создание нового потока — медленная операция.

Comment: VladD, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, если поможет.

Comment: Люблю проверять, сегодня еще почитаю и потестирую.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю это подойдет:

```
private void RunAsync()
{
    string param = "Hello world";
    Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(param));
}

private void MethodWithParameter(string param)
{
    //Do smth
}
```

или так:

```
var x_param = rawData;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Do smth with 'x_param'
});
```

Comment: чёт непонятно , а можно на простейшем примере ?? пожалуйста :3